# std::optional, как вернуть значение из ф-ции

Tags: c++

В случае ошибки, я понимаю что можно вернуть std::nullopt, но при возврате конкретного значения, не компилируется, VS2017 ругается:

> "fatal error C1189: #error:  class template optional is only available with C++17."

Как я понял студия ещё не поддерживает эту штуку? Нужно буст прикручивать?

Comment: Во-первых, чтобы использовать фичи С++17 в VS2017 надо в настройках проекта включить С++17. Во-вторых, словесные рассказы "по мотивам" про ошибки в коде тут никому не интересны. О каком "хорошем раскладе" идет речь не ясно тоже.

Comment: Если нужна какая-то дополнительная информация, так и скажите, я добавлю. Сейчас попробую ваш совет. Всё заработало, спасибо

Comment: Это вопрос не недостающей информации, а лишней. Причесал ваш вопрос, если не возражаете (если возражаете, можете откатить правку).